# Test a callback param with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm pretty new in unit testing and dont know how to test the following circunstances over a callback for this example class:

```
public class Foo {

    private final ItemLoader loader;
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(ItemLoader loader,Bar bar) {
        super();
        this.loader = loader;
        this.bar=bar;
    }

    public void getItems(ItemStore.Callback callback) {
        List<ItemData> itemData = bar.getItemData();
        List<Item> items = this.loader.transform(itemData);
        callback.onItemsLoaded(items);
    }

}
```

- That callback.onItemsLoaded is called with the result of loader.transform

My current test is:

```
public class ExampleTest extends BaseTestCase {

    private Foo foo;

    @Mock
    private Bar mockBar;

    @Mock
    private ItemLoader mockItemLoader;

    @Mock
    private ItemStore.Callback itemLoadCallback;

    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        foo = new Foo(mockItemLoader, mockBar);
    }

    public void testGetItems() {
        List<ItemData> mockItemData = (List<ItemData>) mock(List.class);
        when(mockBar.getItemData()).thenReturn(mockItemData);
        foo.getItems(itemLoadCallback);
        verify(mockItemLoader).transform(mockItemData);
    }

}
```

It tests:

- That loader.transform is called
- That callback.onItemsLoaded is called

But I realised that if I change the last line of the Foo.getItems method like (Notice the null):

```
    public void getItems(ItemStore.Callback callback) {
        ...
        callback.onItemsLoaded(null);
    }
```

The test keep pasing. So I'd need to test that callback.onItemsLoaded is called with the result of loader.transform
So I modified the test:

```
    public void testGetItems() {
        List<ItemData> mockItemData = (List<ItemData>) mock(List.class);
        when(mockBar.getItemData()).thenReturn(mockItemData);
        foo.getItems(itemLoadCallback);
        verify(mockItemLoader).transform(mockItemData);
        List<Item> resultItems = verify(mockItemLoader).transform(mockItemData);
        verify(itemLoadCallback).onItemsLoaded(resultItems);
    }
```

But it complains in the last line saying `Argument(s) are different!`

How can I fix the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `mockItemLoader` is a mock, it will actually return an empty list from `transform`.  If you want to make it return something different, you could set up an object for it to return.  Basically, this will be your own `List<Item>`.  So you can then **stub** the `tranform` method instead of verifying it; and use the same `List<Item>` when you verify the call to `onItemsLoaded`.